# SSRS 2008 Calendar Selector

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm still getting used to migrating from SSRS 2005 to 2008, in 2005 when you set a parameter up inside the report and pointed it to being a date/time the report gave you a calendar to chose your dates (as in a visual cal). I cant for the life of me get it to work in 2008? it just always shows the date/time of the field??

[image]

The data source is in the datetime format.

Comment: Are you populating the parameter from a DataSet?

Comment: yeah, basic one just to return max and min dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention in a comment, you're populating this data with a DataSet.

The screenshot shows normal behaviour in SSRS 2005 and SSRS 2008.

I created a report in 2005 and 2008 with **4** parameters; two with type **Text** and two with type **DateTime**.

Two are populated with a DataSet based on:

```
select date1 = cast('01-jan-2013' as datetime)
union all select date1 = cast('01-feb-2013' as datetime)
```

The other two have a default value of `=Today()`.

You can see that behaviour is almost identical between versions.

**2005:**

[image]

**2008:**

[image]

The only difference is that the Text parameter doesn't convert a date implicitly.

From your perspective the main things to note are that when the parameter is populated by a DataSet, you can only choose from a dropdown of the available values (i.e. what you're seeing in your screenshot), but if the parameter is not popluated from a DataSet (dropdown) you can choose from the calendar picker as expected.